# How can someone be a co-author in a paper by just presenting undocumented evidence?

Tags: authorship, social-science

[This recent paper](http://www.bioone.org/doi/10.2993/0278-0771-37.4.700#) is about birds of prey spreading fires. Some of the co-authors are firefighters which basically tell their personal experience as eyewitnesses to the behavior of these birds but do not present any hard evidence.

How can this be considered enough for co-authorship? Is this an accepted practice in social sciences?

Comment: Can you link to the statement of work? I can’t find a breakdown of what each author contributed.

Comment: Is this question really about authorship or are you complaining about their scientific methods? I don't see any indication in the article that those co-authors' only contributions to the manuscript were their observations, and there are other observers mentioned who are not co-authors. I might have missed something since I did not fully read the linked work.

Comment: Eyewitness accounts are not evidence?

Comment: I'm voting to close because I don't think this question is actually about authorship at all, it seems to be a critique of a paper. I'll retract my close vote if the OP is able to clarify.

Comment: Eyewitness accounts are exactly hard evidence, no?

Comment: @JonCuster How is a eyewitness account reproducible since it doesn't lead to anything more than a story anybody could make up?

Comment: @HermanToothrot where did Jon say anything about reproducibility?

Comment: @HermanToothrot - I'm the only person in the lab. I read a meter, write down the reading in a notebook, and publish results based on the meter reading. I'm in a forest. I see an animal doing something, write that down in a notebook, and publish results based on what I saw. Very little science is performed in front of an independent audience - it is all eyewitness accounts.

Comment: @JonCuster Yes you have a point, that's why I was asking about social/behavioral science. However your two examples are not comparable, reading a meter in a lab is not the same as reporting an animal doing something. I should be able to get almost the same reading if I follow your methodology but a behavior could be a very rare event, so it's not all eyewitness accounts. So a bunch of people that have seen UFOs can write a paper and all be coauthors?

Comment: Clearly it would be better if they had pictures or film (haven't read the article, so I don't know). And lots of people do write papers about UFOs - they just aren't published in mainstream journals.

Comment: This comment thread makes it more and more clear that this is only disguised as a question of authorship.

Comment: @JonCuster you are missing the point, I was discussing reproducibility, results must be reproducible, even though now there is no time,money or interest to do that, it should be a part of the scientific method.

Comment: Well, this spring could well be a big fire season, so lots of interview potential of wild land firefighters. Just like astronomers studying novas have to wait for the next one...

Answer (score 1):

I think the true answer depends on what the other co-authors think.  In my field and particularly for application-oriented papers and case studies, we often add industry representatives or clinical staffs as co-authors, even when they don't contribute much to the writing of the paper.

We do this because it fosters good relationships, demonstrates their facilitation of the analytical work, and (in our belief) is good a "people-practice."

For others, we simply list them in an 'acknowledgements' section with some comments.

It all depends.

Comment: It also recognizes them as "field observers" and their role in bringing the issue to the scientific community as worthy of study. Without them, in this case anyway, there would be no research, no paper.